# Does there exist any tool to generate strongly-typed classes for .Net configuration?

Tags: .net, configurationsection

I'm looking for a tool to generate strongly-typed classes from XML.
I would like to define XML configuration (section, ConfigurationElements etc.) and then generate classes that could handle my configuration through ConfigurationManager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [.NET Configuration Code Generator](http://nconfiggen.codeplex.com/).  It uses a sample of the desired XML to infer the configuration structure and types and generate the code.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is [Configuration Section Designer](http://csd.codeplex.com/)

[image]